# In AVAudioplayer multiple songs play at once.how to fix single song play at a time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to create `AVAudioplayer` programatically.The audio player successfully playing.But i have some issues.I am displaying 12 audio items in UITableview.If i click first item that should navigate audio player view controller.And i click the play button the song will play.If i click back button the song play continuously.But if i click again same item the Audio view controller the view will display initial state like progress bar should not move and current time and song duration are empty.but song play continuously.
And another issue is there. If i click first item that corresponding song will play.I should not click any pass button.i click back button and click second item.if i click second item the audio view controller will display.I click play button the song display.In background first song play and second song also play.This is my second issue.how to solve these two issues.please help me any body.

```
-(void)playOrPauseButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(playing==NO)
    {
        [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // Here Pause.png is a image showing Pause Button.
        NSError *err=nil;
        AVAudioSession *audioSession=[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@ %d",urlsArray,selectedIndex);
        NSString *sourcePath=[urlsArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
        NSData *objectData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sourcePath]];
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:objectData error:&err];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        audioPlayer.delegate=self;
        [audioPlayer play];
        playing=YES;
    }
    else if (playing==YES)
    {
        [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [audioPlayer pause];
        playing=NO;
    }
    if (self.audioPlayer)
    {
        [self updateViewForPlayerInfo];
        [self updateViewForPlayerState];
        [self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    }
}
-(void)updateViewForPlayerInfo
{
    self.songDuration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)self.audioPlayer.duration / 60, (int)self.audioPlayer.duration % 60, nil];
    NSLog(@"%f", self.audioPlayer.duration);
    self.progressBar.maximumValue = self.audioPlayer.duration;
    self.volumeSlider.value = self.audioPlayer.volume;
}
-(void)updateViewForPlayerState
{
    [self updateCurrentTime];
    if (self.updatedTimer)
    {
        [self.updatedTimer invalidate];
    }
    if (self.audioPlayer.playing)
    {
        self.updatedTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateCurrentTime) userInfo:self.audioPlayer repeats:YES];
    }
}
-(void)updateCurrentTime
{
    //NSLog(@"self.audioPlayer.currentTime = %f", self.audioPlayer.currentTime);
    self.currentTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)self.audioPlayer.currentTime / 60, (int)self.audioPlayer.currentTime % 60, nil];
    self.progressBar.value = self.audioPlayer.currentTime;
}
-(void)volumeSliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender
{
    self.audioPlayer.volume=[sender value];
}
```

Comment: help me any body.I am struck in this issue..help me plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:objectData error:&err];
```

Each time you are creating the audioPlayer object. So my suggestion is check for audioPlayer before creating the object like this

```
if(audioPlayer)
{
audioPlayer.delegate=nil;
audioPlayer=nil;
}
```

Then create the object.

Comment: thanks for your response.I am using your logic.But still same problem getting. plz help me brother. i am stuck in this porblem

Comment: Using this is your problem of playing 2 song at the same time is resolved or not??

Comment: are you still allocating the AVAudioPlayer object again and again??

Comment: no brother. i am creating AVAudioplayer object only once na

Comment: So you decide it by checking the playing value?? im right?? if so have you checked whether it is going into the same if loop or not. try debug or print value of playing in NSLog.

Comment: ya.is there any wrong from my side.brother plz come to chating.if you are free come to chating

Comment: sure. Im free we can do the chating

Comment: ya lets we will meet on charing.accept my question and send me chatting invitation. bro.i will also give up vote to ur answer.you also give my question upvote

Comment: come to chating brother

Comment: searching for how to send invitation

Comment: brother do u find a solution for invitation?

Comment: hi come to chating bro. i sent invitation

Comment: brother i think u r busy?

Comment: no yaar but i m not getting any link. so pls provide me step

Comment: i am not find any solution for how to send chat invitaion

Comment: did you got any idea how to send chat invitation?

Comment: brother tell me how to solve my issue in audio player.still i had same problem

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50242/avaudio-player-problem start discussion

Comment: Pls open the link chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50242/avaudio-player-problem  and start discussion

Answer (score 0):

In short what's happening is the following:

1. you click on the table cell
2. you create an audio player view controller
3. You play the audio - your audio player itself is retained for some reason (Unclear why - are you using ARC?)
4. You click the back button - the Audio player view controller is released
5. you click the table cell again - and create a new audio player view controller with it's own player!

Basically - if you want the previous song continue playing even when your exiting the Audio player view controller - and to have only a single player for the audio - I would hold it in a singleton class that will manage the player , or as a property of the app delegate.

This way - when you enter the Audio Player view controller - It will check the following:

1. If a player doesn't exist - create it and assign it the item - ready to play
2. If a player exists but it's the same item - just update the controls to show it's current playing status.
3. If a player exists but it's another item - either don't update the controls - and when the user hits play - replace the item in the player and start updating the controls - or stop the song as you display the Audio player view controller. (Up to you - I don't know the design of your app obviously)

Comment: thanks for your response.yes i am using ARC.but i can't understand your post.please tell me briefly  or give any example how to solve my issue.thanks in advance.....

Comment: Hold the player in the app delegate as a property and always use it instead of self.audioplayer. This way technically you won't be able to create and play more then once.

Answer (score 0):

In working with AVAudioPlayer, I use a property to keep up with the player.  Based on looking at your code it isn't clear to me that you are keeping the player around, or that you aren't instantiating a new instance every time.  Based on your description, it sounds like you ARE instantiating a new instance - don't think you want that.

So in your .h file, something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *myAVAudioPlayer;
```

and then the corresponding @synthesize in your .m file.

When you want to move from one song to the next, simply stop playing current - then reload a new URL using an init for your self.myAVAudioPlayer property.  You MUST then call the prepareToPlay method again for the AVAudioPlayer option.

You probably will make it easier on yourself by not managing the variables regarding playing or not (it looked like you were doing that from your post).  Use your property and check by accessing the setter/getter for the property for state of the player:

```
if(!self.myAVAudioPlayer)
{
// allocate and initialize using the code you have

[self.myAVAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
} else 

if  ([self.myAVAudioPlayer isPlaying])
{
//do whatever you need for isPlaying - looks like pause
} else

if (![self.myAVAudioPlayer isPlaying])
{
// do whatever you need to do if the player isn't playing when the button is pressed
// at this point you will likely just re-init with a new URL and reset other items
// don't forget to call -prepareToPlay again
}
```

Here is a link to another approach which takes advantage of AVPlayerItem --> click https://stackoverflow.com/a/22254588/3563814